# 'allow access from selected network' on storage accout vs Blob

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have storage account with `'allow access from selected network'` set to a subnet.
This should be applicable to everything inside the storage account.
But in 'Configuration' menu of storage account there is another setting just for Blob called `'Allow Blob public access'`
Why there is a special public access just for blob when storage account already have options for it? How is this affecting the storage account setting? Do they override each other?

Comment: Hi, can my answer answer your question?:)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, these are different things.

For example, If you have a .txt file in a container and the container's access level is 'container'. Then if you go to the browser to access the file, you will get something like this:

[image]

After you set the `Allow Blob public access` to disable, then you will get this in the browser:

[image]

But if you use `allow access from selected network`, then if you don't let the app or something have the white list IP address or allowed subnet, you will be unable to access the resources. The server will return a 404 or 403 error, just as the resources never exist.

To simply say, `Allow Blob public access` just prohibit blob from anonymous accessing, but `allow access from selected network` will private blob and even the other resources like files, table, and queues from accessing when the app is not in the white list IP address or allowed subnet.